# Identity 'Custom User Data' not working in .NET 5

Tags: asp.net-identity

.NET 5; Visual Studio 2019, Version 16.9.4

I created a new ASP.NET Core MVC web app running on .NET 5.

When I run the app and register it prompts to 'Apply Migrations' and then creates the database with the standard Identity tables.

I then delete the database and add an ApplicationUser with Custom User Data following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-5.0

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.5" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="5.0.5" />

  public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
  {
      [MaxLength(50)]
      public string FirstName { get; set; }
      [MaxLength(50)]
      public string LastName { get; set; }
  }

  public class AlbumDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
  {
      public AlbumDbContext(DbContextOptions<AlbumDbContext> options)
             : base(options) {}
  }


  using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;  

    services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
      .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AlbumDbContext>()
      .AddDefaultUI();
```

.AddDefaultIdentity is the the default for the 'ASP.NET Core Web App (Model-View-Controller)' template.

If I try to change it to `AddIdentity` I get an error

> IServiceCollection does not contain AddIdentity

Adding a migration and updating the database runs without error and the two `ApplicationUser` fields are added to the `AspNetUsers` table.

Now when I run the app I get an error:

> InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' has been registered

I've reviewed the numerous posts on the issue and have not found a solution.

Is there something I'm missing, that is undocumented or is this a bug? Being able to add custon data is a pretty basic function for Identity.

Answer (score 0):

The cited article says to Update the Pages/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml which doesn't exist since Identity is provided as a Razor Class Library so I had ignored that part.

However there is a Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml and if I change IdentityUser to ApplicationUser the app now runs.

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager
```